# first letter capital and other are small latter after each dot (.) in div html

Tags: html

when open in browser it show : "This is first sentence. this is second sentence. this is third sentence. this is end." 
and I want like 
"This is first sentence. This is second sentence. This is third sentence. This is end." Capital latter after each dot.

Comment: code is <html>
<head>
 <style>
  div:first-letter {text-transform:uppercase}
  div {text-transform:lowercase}
 </style>
</head>
<body >
  <div >
    THIS IS FIRST SENTENCE.
    THIS IS SECOND SENTENCE.
    This Is Third Sentence.
    this is end. 
  </div>
</body>
<html>

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done using only CSS without modifying your HTML. According to your code, you are telling CSS to transform the first letter of the div to uppercase, and this is exactly what it is doing. A simple way to achieve what you want is to do the following:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <style>  
        span {display: inline-block; text-transform:lowercase} 
        span:first-letter {text-transform:uppercase}
    </style> 
</head> 
<body > 
    <div > 
        <p>
            <span>THIS IS FIRST SENTENCE.</span><span>THIS IS SECOND SENTENCE.</span><span>This Is Third Sentence.</span><span> this is end.</span> 
        </p>
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Note that you cannot apply pseudo-selector `:first-letter` to inline elements, so you must specify `display: inline-block` in your CSS. I hope this helps!

**Edit:** Since you don't want to include any extra tags in your HTML, you need to use Javascript. For this I will be using jQuery and assume the following HTML:

```
    <html> 
<head> 
    <style>  
        div{text-transform:lowercase} 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body > 
    <div id="myDiv"> 
         This is first sentence. this is second sentence. this is third sentence. this is end.
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Afterwards, insert a `<script>` tag with a function like this:

```
<script>    
function sentenceCase(input, lowercaseBefore) {
        input = ( input === undefined || input === null ) ? '' : input;
        if (lowercaseBefore) { input = input.toLowerCase(); }
        return input.toString().replace( /(^|\. *)([a-z])/g, function(match, separator, char) {
        return separator + char.toUpperCase();
    });
}
</script>
```

Then, to use it you need to assign your div content to a variable as follows (include this snippet inside the `<script></script>` tag:

```
var content = $('#mydiv').text(); //You assign 'This is first sentence. this is second sentence. this is third sentence. this is end.' to content
content = sentenceCase(content);
$('#mydiv').text(content);
```

Comment: my sentence is continues "THIS IS FIRST SENTENCE.THIS IS SECOND SENTENCE.This Is Third Sentence.this is end." no scope to add <p>

Comment: I editted my answer to do it with span inside the same p element. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I already said that I have one complete paragraph, there are no scope to add any thing in between this paragraph like <span>

Comment: Please, have a look at my new edit, this allows you to modify your content without adding any extra HTML tags. But as I said you will need Javascript (and jQuery in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on your div and add css element to that class.

```
<html> 
<head>
<style>
.para {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.para:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style> 
</head> 
<body > 
<div class="para"> THIS IS FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS SECOND SENTENCE. This Is Third Sentence. this is end. </div>
</body> 
<html>
```

Comment: this code convert sentence  like "This is first sentence. this is second sentence. this is third sentence. this is end." and I want "This is first sentence. This is second sentence. This is third sentence. This is end." first latter capital after each dot (.) .